# Angular2 - Add 3rd Party Javascript Library (Summernote)

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular2 and trying to use 3rd party libraries in it. Trying to use summernote Js plugin, used for rich text area. http://summernote.org/getting-started/

This is my **my-summernote.component.ts** file.

```
import { ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterViewInit, Component} from '@angular/core';
import '../../assets/plugins/summernote/summernote.min.js';

declare var jQuery: any;

@Component({
    selector: 'my-summernote',
    templateUrl: './my-summernote.template.html'
})
export class SummerNoteComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    constructor(){   
     }
    ngAfterViewInit() {        
        jQuery("#theTextArea").summernote();
    }
}
```

And here is **my-summernote.template.html** file

```
<textarea class="form-control" name="theTextArea" id="theTextArea">                              
    </textarea>
```

I've included the jquery in **index.html** file, But i'm getting following error

```
    Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "codemirror"
        at webpackMissingModule (main.bundle.js:2211)
        at b.function.Array.reduce.Array.reduce.e (main.bundle.js:2211)
        at Object.505 (main.bundle.js:2211)
    Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'codemirror' in C:\Project\Community3.0\CommunityAng\src\assets\plugins\summernote
resolve module codemirror in C:\Project\Community3.0\CommunityAng\src\assets\plugins\summernote
  looking for modules in C:\Project\Community3.0\CommunityAng\src
    C:\Project\Community3.0\CommunityAng\src\codemirror doesn't exist (module as directory)
    resolve 'file' codemirror in C:\Project\Community3.0\CommunityAng\src
      resolve file
```

Can someone please guide what i'm missing.

Comment: Where are you including `codemirror` file?

Comment: I have not included it. May be it can be from this plugin. But i can't find it in official documentation site as well. http://summernote.org/getting-started/#run-summernote

Answer (score 1):

install bootstrap, summernote, ng2-summernote via npm.

- in .angular-cli.json

{

```
{"styles": [
"styles.css",
"../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
"../node_modules/summernote/dist/summernote.css"
],

"scripts": [
"../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
"../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
"../node_modules/summernote/dist/summernote.min.js",
"../node_modules/summernote/dist/lang/summernote-es-ES.min.js"
]}
```

}

- add Ng2Summernote in declarations of app.module.ts

  import { Ng2Summernote } from 'ng2-summernote/ng2-summernote';
- html and js

  `<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
          <ng2-summernote [(ngModel)]="text"></ng2-summernote>
      </div>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="submit()"> Submit</button>
  <div>
      {{model.text}}
  </div>`

  `import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
  import { Ng2Summernote } from 'ng2-summernote/ng2-summernote';
  @Component({
    selector: 'app-summernote-richtext',
    templateUrl: './summernote-richtext.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./summernote-richtext.component.css']
  })
  export class SummernoteRichtextComponent implements OnInit {`

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    }
    uploadData:string; 
    text: string = 'appendix';
    data: string = 'appendix';
    model:any = {};
    imgSrc = '/assets/img.jpg'
    options: any = {
        height: 100,
        toolbar: [['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
        ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']]
        ]
    };
    disabled: boolean = false;
    submit(){
      this.model.text = this.text;
    }
  }